# What is the best way to find photos where ALL tags to be searched on are in the photos using FQL?

Tags: facebook, photo, facebook-fql, photo-tagging

If I want to use FQL to search for photos where 2 people are in the photos I can do this using the following code -

```
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . '/fql?q=SELECT+src_big+FROM+photo+WHERE+pid+IN(SELECT+pid+FROM+photo_tag+WHERE+subject+IN('.$tag_list.'))' . '&access_token=' . $params['access_token'];
```

Where the $tag_list variable is a comma separated list of user ids.

This returns the photos where either of those users are tagged in the photo.

However what if I want to find photos where BOTH of the people appear (are tagged) in the photos. Is there a good way to do this? What if I want to find a large group of people in the photos. Is it best just to iterate over the results and check that all users are in the photos once the result is returned?

anyone else tackled this? 
many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fql?q=
SELECT src_big 
  FROM photo 
 WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject ='{uid1}') 
   AND pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject ='{uid2}')
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I dont know how many userids i want to find? My code will be in PHP so should I simply create a function which loops the number of userids to look for and constructs the FQL query adding the "AND pid IN (SELECT pid..." line for each user id to look for? or is there a more elegant way using a single query that instead of IN which finds any of the ids IN (1,2,3) would only return results where all of the ids are present (1,2,3). thanks for your answer.

Comment: just keep adding the AND pid IN line over and over. However, you will run into a length issue at some point  However, your original question was specifically worded for 2 (two) users.  I've answered that correctly, please at least give me credit for that and accept the answer

Comment: Thanks, my original question also posed the problem of how to find a large group of people (more than 2). Thanks for the clarification I will experiment with how effective this is and try some other solutions. Thanks again for your answer. peace.